# Is it possible to power STM32 Nucleo Boards from a 3.7 Lithium Ion battery?

Tags: power, batteries, stm32, lithium-ion, nucleo

I have a Lithium Ion Battery that produces 3.7 volts and i would like to use it to power my STM32L476RG Nucleo board to collect data on the ADC and push the data to SD Card.

I understand that i can power the Nucleo from external 5 volts but is there a way to power it on 3.7 Volts without needing a boost converter?

Comment: STM32, yes, Nucleo, likely not unless you verify that the loaded dropout voltage of the utilized regulator will always be less than the difference between the loaded cell voltage and 3.3v.  To intentionally design an STM32 system for a lithium cell, you might use a 3v or even 2.8v regulator chosen for a low dropout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STM32 Nucleo boards use an [LD39030](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ld39050.pdf) to drop the 5V power input to 3.3V. This regulator has a typical dropout voltage of 0.2V at 500mA (proportionally less at lower current), so the Li-ion battery would have to stay above 3.5V at maximum board current.

Provided you use a suitably sized battery it should work fine, though the effective battery capacity may be reduced. Most li-ion cells can produce over 3.5V for ~70% of their *actual* capacity at low current draw.

Example: [Sanyo/Panasonic NCR18650GA 3500mAh](http://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/Sanyo%20NCR18650GA%203500mAh%20(Red)%20UK.html)

[image]

For battery health you should avoid using more than 80% anyway, so 70% is not bad.

Comment: My application daws less than 50mA of current constantly (between 10-20mA at all times). So is the dropout even smaller? Meaning I can use more of the battery? What pins do I apply the li ion battery to?

Comment: @Taako, what does the datasheet tell you about your dropout question?

Comment: @DiBosco the datasheet says that at 50mA it's dropout is only 50mV. So im good on that. But in wondering if I should be applying the battery to hrthe 5V input or the 3.3V input

Comment: What does the STM32 datasheet tell you about connecting 3.7V to its Vcc pin?

Comment: 6.3.2 External power supply inputs: VIN and E5V says that VIN mus tbe 7-12 Volts and E5V must be 4.75 V to 5.25 V so it looks like im out of luck on that end. 

6.3.3 External power supply input: + 3.3V
 says it can be 3.0-3.6 volts so i'm pretty close to being able to do that but 100mV off.

Comment: I suggest you examine the board schematic. The regulator input comes directly from +5V, so I think the only real limit is its dropout voltage. Do not connect the battery directly to 3.3V -  when fully charged it will blow up the MCU!

Comment: The problem is 100mV "off" is 100mV outside the absolute maximum ratings, which could fatally damage the STM32. I was just trying to nudge you in the right direction without spoon feeding the answer. It's important to start to understand how to read datasheets.